# Cannot connect to minIO via spark operator on Kubernetes - Connection refused

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, minio

getting

```
INFO AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection refused (Connection refused)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

when trying to read data from minIO via spark. I am running my spark jar via spark operator on Kubernetes on WSL2 + Docker Desktop. MinIO is also run on Kubernetes in a separate namespace.

my spark context settings:

```
val s3endPointLoc = "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", s3endPointLoc)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", s3accessKeyAws)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", s3secretKeyAws)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.connection.timeout", connectionTimeOut)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", "100")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "true")
```

What might be the reason for the refused connection? thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply connect via `http://127.0.0.1:9000`

You should provide the MinIO service DNS name to Spark: `<MinIO-ServiceName>.<MinIO-Namespace>.svc.cluster.local:9000`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Trying to connect to the minIO service gives AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: streaming.minio-svc.minio.svc.cluster.local: Name or service not known - streaming is the name of the bucket, the rest should correspond to the convention you suggested/described on https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/ My endpoint in spark is s3endPointLoc = "minio-svc.minio.svc.cluster.local:9000 and the name of service in namespace minio is minio-svc - what could be set up wrong?